# How to make password change prompt confirmation in SettingsActivity for Android?

Tags: java, android, edittextpreference

I have a Settings Activity in Android Studio and a password List item that when clicked prompts an `EditTextPreference` dialogue with `InputType` password. How can I make it so that when the user enters the password, another Dialog pops up asking the user to confirm the password change.

Or even better, how can I make the `EditTextPreference` multi line and prompt for old password, new password, confirm new password within the same Dialog?

I added the following in my main activity's onCreate

```
ListView lv;
Context ctx=this;

onCreate() {



lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 1) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Values");
                final EditText oldPass = new EditText(ctx);
                final EditText newPass = new EditText(ctx);
                final EditText confirmPass = new EditText(ctx);


                oldPass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                newPass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                confirmPass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());


                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(ctx);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                ll.addView(oldPass);

                ll.addView(newPass);
                ll.addView(confirmPass);
                alertDialog.setView(ll);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = alertDialog.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But there is no change in the behavior of the app. The listItem I'm focusing on is second from the top so presumably position == 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a `LinearLayout` and added two `textBoxes` into it and then gave it to the `alertBox`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
alertDialog.setTitle("Values");
final EditText oldPass = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
final EditText newPass = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
final EditText confirmPass = new EditText(MainActivity.this);


oldPass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
newPass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
confirmPass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

oldPass.setHint("Old Password");
newPass.setHint("New Password");
confirmPass.setHint("Confirm Password");
LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

ll.addView(oldPass);

ll.addView(newPass);
ll.addView(confirmPass);         
alertDialog.setView(ll);
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

AlertDialog alert11 = alertDialog.create();
alert11.show();
```

Check the passwords with the object references `oldPass` and `newPass`.

If you want to add anymore objects on to it, just create and add to the view.

**To deal with the problem that when I cancel or pressed yes in this new dialog, the old dialog would appear, I changed "EditTextPreference" to simply "Preference" in my pref_general.xml file. Now the old dialogue does not appear or show up at all and the problem is fixed.**

Comment: So for this solution would I have to override the onItemClickListener for the settings listview to launch this dialogue rather than the default one given?

Comment: Yes, you can use whereever you want to.

Comment: in `onItemClickListener` get the password from the `Listitem` and set it to oldPassword if you want, show the dialog box

Comment: Ok I'm trying it out. The template android studio provides for a Settings Activity doesn't even include an explicit listener I guess (may be wrong) so I have to write it out myself.

Comment: OK thanks I got it working, but when I press "No" the old dialogue pops up even though I have (at)Override before my click listener. Will this just be bypassed when I add my code to replace dialog.cancel() or is there a way I can completely override that original dialogue?

Comment: remove the old dialog before this and keep it in the yes button click event.

Comment: It's not an explicit dialogue though that I can just remove because this is the settings activity template provided by android studio. Or is there an easy way I can do this?

Comment: I don't know about that. I'm sorry. You could post a question about that. someone else experienced in that could definitely help